# Flex div has height of 228px even though there is no content inside of it and I haven't specified size anywhere

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For some reason, a div whose parent has a `display: flex property` is having a height of 228px even though there's no content inside of it.

Image example

[image]

```css
    .sights-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex: 1;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .sights-list div {
        flex-basis: 48%;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class='sights-list'>
    <div>

    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Padding perhaps?

Comment: Your snippet doesn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Updated question as it turned out the problem is not even related to the <p> element.

Comment: Not much we can do to help since your code sample doesn't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```css
 {
  min-height: 100%;
  
}
```